# file size different readings on linux and python3

Tags: linux, python3

I have some files in the terminal folder. As seen in the picture the size of the file is 33 kB, when I keep the mouse on it reads 33.88 kB.

[image]

However, when check the same file`s size using both os.stat and os.path I get a different number(in bytes). Where do I do wrong? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make long story short, Python's `os.stat()` outputs size in bytes. However, your file manager shows size in [Kibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte), which is a measure in powers of 2 instead of 10 as Kilobytes do (and because computer science for the most part uses powers of 2, while average consumers are more familiar with powers of 10).

[image]

To be more specific, Python's `os.stat()` shows size depending on the type of file; to [quote documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html):

> The interpretation of “file size” changes according to the file type. For plain files this is the size of the file in bytes. For FIFOs and sockets under most flavors of Unix (including Linux in particular), the “size” is the number of bytes waiting to be read at the time of the call to os.stat(), os.fstat(), or os.lstat(); this can sometimes be useful, especially for polling one of these special files after a non-blocking open. The meaning of the size field for other character and block devices varies more, depending on the implementation of the underlying system call.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I  thought  they are different comparing with kilobytes!